# Can I make partial plots for DecisionTreeClassifier in scikit-learn (and R)

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn

I have some old code using scikit-learn's DecisionTreeClassifier. I'd like to make partial plots based on this classifier.

All the examples I've seen so far (such as http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence.plot_partial_dependence.html) use "GradientBoostingRegressor" as the classifier.

My question is, is it possible to make partial plots for other classifier?(eg.DecisionTreeClassifier). I've tried the following code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence import plot_partial_dependence
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1

X, y = make_friedman1()
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_features='auto').fit(X,y)
fig, axs = plot_partial_dependence(clf, X, [0, (0, 1)])
```

and it doesn't work.

```
ValueError: gbrt has to be an instance of BaseGradientBoosting
```

I've found some comments on the internet(Quora):

> Partial dependence plots don't depend on the particular choice of classifier at all. The partial dependence plot module used for the gradient boosting example would work fine if you swapped in a random forest classifier.

However, I still don't know how it works.

Also for R, it seems I can make partial plots for randomForest package. However, I'm not exactly sure how the random forest is implemented, in the R manual the author Andy Liaw cite the reference "Friedman, J. (2001). Greedy function approximation: the gradient boosting machine, Ann. of Stat."

Does this mean I have to use gradient-boosting in order to get partial plots?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As your error message states, you must use a classifier that has a base class of `BaseGradientBoosting`.

From the documentation you posted:

> gbrt : BaseGradientBoosting
>
> A fitted gradient boosting model

Both `GradientBoostingClassifier` and `GradientBoostingRegressor` inherit from `BaseGradientBoosting` ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py)), so either one of those classes should work, in theory. As for the rest of those classifiers, they do not appear to be supported by the `plot_partial_dependence` function.

Answer (score 1):

This has been bugging me for a while - PDPs only available on gbrt classifiers.

Fortunately this has been addressed and a new sklearn release (3 weeks ago or so) means it's possible to do PDP on all classifiers!

Efforts are described here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/12599 (I had nothing to do with it FYI, just a grateful end-user)

Comment: please use 
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence instead of sklearn.ensemble.partial_dependence.partial_dependence

Answer (score 0):

Partial dependence plot is a method to discover feature interaction with target feature in specific model. You can think of it as the coefficient (beta) in linear regression model, only partial dependence can be used in non-linear model, and tell you how the model is interpreting the feature at each different value of feature. And another difference is that feature interaction will have much bigger play in most non-linear model. The fact that scikit-learn does not support partial_dependence plot for model other than gbrt, does not mean you cannot apply the method to the model. (which is kinda sad, I was waiting for their update for quite long).

Here is an example of applying partial dependence on Xgb model in Python.
https://xiaoxiaowang87.github.io/monotonicity_constraint/

And this post also illustrate how it is being calculated. https://medium.com/usf-msds/intuitive-interpretation-of-random-forest-2238687cae45 So you can use this logic to create your own function.

Also, R libraries has partial dependence plot for the RandomForest model (I have not used R for a while, could not remember the exact name of the library).